# How can I use Rc::clone while casting to a trait object?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

The Rust book says that it's idiomatic to use `Rc::clone(&x)` rather than `x.clone()` with `Rc` values, so that it's obvious that this is not your typical `clone`. I'm all for this, but I'm having trouble applying the theory in practice.

I want to clone a reference-counted struct, but cast the clone to a trait object. I can do this using `rc.clone()`, but *not* by using `Rc::clone(&rc)`. This is... strange to me.

```rust
struct ListView {}
trait View {}
impl View for ListView {}

fn very_contrived_example() {
    let list_view: Rc<ListView> = Rc::new(ListView {});
    let mut views: Vec<Rc<dyn View>> = Vec::new();

    // Using Rc::clone does not work:

    // error[E0308]: mismatched types
    //
    // views.push(Rc::clone(&list_view));
    //                      ^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn View`, found struct `ListView`
    //
    // note: expected reference `&Rc<dyn View>`
    //          found reference `&Rc<ListView>`

    // Using a cast works in this very contrived example, but has the
    // disadvantage of moving `list_view`, for some reason, which is not
    // acceptable in general:
    // views.push(Rc::clone(&(list_view as Rc<dyn View>)));

    // But invoking it using method syntax works fine, without a move:
    views.push(list_view.clone());
}
```

What is the difference between `Rc::clone(&x)` and `x.clone()`? What function is `x.clone()` actually invoking? What is the type of `self`? Can I invoke it directly?

What is the idiomatic way to write this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a rare failure of type inference. Explicitly passing the correct explicit type works:

```
views.push(Rc::<ListView>::clone(&list_view))
```

The problem is that `Rc::clone(&list_view)` infers the `T` in `Rc<T>` based on the *expected type* (which is `Rc<dyn View>`), not on the argument type. On the other hand, when you call `list_view.clone()` it uses the implementation of `Clone` on the type of `list_view` and thus it resolves to `Rc::<ListView>::clone`.

---

If the above problem  occurs very often in your code and you would like to keep a visual distinction between normal clones and refcounted shallow clones, you can write a little helper trait:

```
trait RcClone : Clone {
    fn rc_clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.clone()
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> RcClone for Rc<T> { }
impl<T: ?Sized> RcClone for Arc<T> { }
```

Then you can write `list_view.rc_clone()` in your code base which will only work for refcounted types. This still indicates the semantics different from the regular clone while not having the type inference issues.